# React useref not adding focus state to field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to find a solution for this, where I'd like to add the focus state to my input field. But it doesn't seem to be working:

```
const textareaRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
...

const handleClick = () => {
        if (textareaRef.current) {
            alert('Field clicked');
            textareaRef.current.focus();
            textareaRef.current.click();
        }
    };

...

<input
     ref={textareaRef}
     onClick={handleClick}
     onFocus={(e) => e.persist()}
     spellCheck="false"
/>
```

This doesn't work, and the main reason is to show the mobile keyboard. See video here of it not working https://share.getcloudapp.com/jkuYLqO5 and here without alert https://share.getcloudapp.com/wbuKwrLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the bug on desktop browser. What browser is it in the screen recording?

```js
function App() {
  const textareaRef = React.useRef();
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (textareaRef.current) {
        console.log('Field clicked');
        textareaRef.current.focus();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={handleClick}>click me to focus input</div>
      <input
       ref={textareaRef}
       onFocus={(e) => e.persist()}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yea this is really odd. It's the simulator for iphone safari browser.

Comment: Ah I see. It's not in the same component. The click is happening in a child component. Do you think I can get it to work in a child component click to focus it? @hackape

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This got me in the right direction :) I triggered the click on the div element and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in **useEffect()** Hook. Below component mocks your scenario. As the component loads, I make focus() appear on input.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';


const UseRefBasics = () => {
  const refContainer = useRef(null);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(refContainer.current.value);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(refContainer.current);
    refContainer.current.focus();
  });

  return (
    <>
      <form className='form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <input type='text' ref={refContainer} />
        </div>
        <button type='submit'>submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default UseRefBasics;
```

This is a general scenario that I have given. You may use **useEffect()** and get your focus when the state updates by providing another argument to `useEffect(()=>{},[state1])` or in whatever way you need it.